# Разработка веб-приложение на java

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, websocket, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте!

Разработал HTTP server, который может получать и возвращать запросы (Request и Response), сервер может делать и еще дополнительные задачи...

Теперь я хочу построить веб-приложение на java и протестировать свой сервер.

Могу ли я по обычному принципу создать веб-приложение с сервлетами и 
WebContent-ми и вместо Tomcat или GlassFish использовать свой сервер?

Заранее Благодарю!

Comment: @Chubatiy не нужно оформлять кодом то, что не является кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне. Вам достаточно создать веб-приложение и запустить его на сервере.

Про создание web-приложений можете [тут](http://java-course.ru/student/book1/simple-web/) почитать.

Comment: Значит сервер это уже достаточно. То бишь - если я его запускаю и параллельно захожу на какую либо страницу уже все работает и информацию для обработки сервер уже выполняет, и вы хотите сказать что если я сейчас создам свой некий мини веб-сайт и запущу свой сервер то он должен уже будет реагировать и на localhost ? ...    Заранее Благодарю

Comment: @morris понимаете. Если вы отдельно запустите сервер, а отдельно свое приложение, то и работать они будут отдельно друг от друга. У сервера есть директория, которая хранит в себе web-проекты. Вы, соответственно, помещаете свое приложение в данную дерикторию сервера, а затем запускаете сам сервер. Так это работает на Tomcat, GlassFish и других сервера.

Но, поскольку у вас свой собственный сервер, то вам должно быть виднее, как на нем запустить свое приложение.